# Select does not work when combined with Radio in Chakra-UI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, chakra-ui

I have a design where I need to combine radio group and select items together. Specifically, when a user select an option, then need to select an item from the list.

My implementation at https://codesandbox.io/s/chakra-radio-select-cv6r0?file=/src/index.tsx shows how it should look.

However, when I click on the list to select from drop down, nothing happens.

The select works independently, but not when nested inside RadioGroup. This is reproducible on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/chakra-radio-select-cv6r0?file=/src/index.tsx)

Could someone help me understand what is incorrect here and what I need to do to be able to select the item from the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `Select` input outside of the `Radio` component like this

```js
<Flex alignItems={"center"}>
  <Radio value={"LIST"}>
    <Text ml={2}>List</Text>
  </Radio>
  <Select
    w="unset"
    ml={4}
    placeholder="Select List"
    onChange={() => console.log("change")}
    value={"option 1"}
  >
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  </Select>
</Flex>
```